# unable to run the app in xcode 4.6.3 for mac app development

Tags: xcode, macos

unable to run the app in xcode 4.6.3 for mac application development.Its showing message as **could not launch the app...connection refused**.xcode is working fine for ios applications.

Answer (score 0):

just check your etc/host file and local host should be 127.0.0.1.If it is not then edit that one in terminal but be sure when typing the command for opening the host file in terminal.